# Which option did Harry Potter pick for the knight bus?

Tags: harry-potter, knight-bus

In this quote

> ‘Eleven Sickles,’ said Stan, ‘but for firteen you get ’ot chocolate,
>   and for fifteen you get an ’ot-water bottle an’ a toofbrush in the
>   colour of your choice.’ Harry rummaged once more in his trunk,
>   extracted his money bag and shoved some silver into Stan’s hand.

We learn that there are three options for the knight bus.

Is there any canon (or pseudo-canon) sources for which option Harry paid for?

Comment: The book describes in some detail about how Harry is in a state of shock, and worry. He's scared to be ejected from the wizarding world and made to live with the Dursleys. It's fair to say that he wouldn't be thinking about hot chocolate and toothpaste, first and foremost. It might be reasonable to suggest that he didn't choose at all, just paid enough. As @radhil points out, tho, it appears he paid enough for hot chocolate.

Comment: Asking the important questions.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Nothing says for sure, but he at least paid for chocolate.**  From the book, just after the conversation about Sirius' escape:

> After a while, Stan remembered that Harry had paid for hot chocolate, but poured it all over Harry's pillow when the bus moved abruptly from Anglesey to Aberdeen.

Nothing is ever mentioned of a hot water bottle or a toothbrush after Stan's pitch.  It's possible he forgot about these as well if Harry was just too distracted to count and just shoved money at him (which the book does say), but I think we can presume Harry just paid for the hot chocolate.